# jQuery - one form is affecting the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a page with multiple forms (all the forms have the same classes, just unique IDs). The form has a functionality where people can enter their starting and ending work date. There is also a checkbox for "I currently work here", and if that is checked, the ending work date input field will be replaced with the word "present" instead.

Clicking/toggling the checkbox works just fine for each separate form. The issue is that when the checkbox in one form is pre-checked, all the other forms have the word 'present' even if the checkboxes in the respective forms are not checked.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.checkbox-present').length) {
        var presentCheckBox = $('.checkbox-present');
        var endYear = $(presentCheckBox).parents('.checkbox-parent').find('.position-end');
        if ($(presentCheckBox, endYear).is(':checked')) {
            $('.form-group', endYear).hide();
            $(endYear).append('<p class="position-present">Present</p>');
        }
    } else {
        $('.position-present', endYear).remove();
        $('.form-group', endYear).show();
    }
});

$('.checkbox-present').change(function () {
    var endYear = $(this).parents('.checkbox-parent').find('.position-end');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.form-group', endYear).hide();
        $(endYear).append('<p class="position-present">Present</p>')
    } else {
        $('.position-present', endYear).remove();
        $('.form-group', endYear).show();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here to properly see the effect.](http://jsfiddle.net/gummybearpaws/mnLkaoo1/6/)

As you can see from the fiddle, Form 2 has the word "present" even if its checkbox is unchecked. I'm certain it's because of the checkbox in Form 1.

How do I fix this? I'm still finding my way around jQuery so I'm not sure how to solve this, but I think it has something to do with binding?

Comment: you actually have no forms ....`<form></form>`. If planning to submit to server will need form tags to make it the simplest for submit ( it is possible to serialize without but since you said you are just learning will be far easier)

Comment: @charlietfl yes, this is just a snippet of the entire code..  thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you are checking the checked condition, if any of the checkbox is checked it will select all of them

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.checkbox-present').length) {
        var presentCheckBox = $('.checkbox-present:checked');
        if (presentCheckBox.length) {
            var endYear = $(presentCheckBox).parents('.checkbox-parent').find('.position-end');
            $('.form-group', endYear).hide();
            $(endYear).append('<p class="position-present">Present</p>');
        }
    } else {
        $('.position-present', endYear).remove();
        $('.form-group', endYear).show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n061kuym/1/)

---

But instead of repeating the logic again you can

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkbox-present').change(function() {
    var endYear = $(this).closest('.checkbox-parent').find('.position-end');
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.form-group', endYear).hide();
      $(endYear).append('<p class="position-present">Present</p>')
    } else {
      $('.position-present', endYear).remove();
      $('.form-group', endYear).show();
    }
  }).filter(':checked').change();
});
```

```css
section {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="clearfix">

  <h3>FORM 1</h3>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Time Period</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 checkbox-parent">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-present" checked/>
        <label for="work-1">I currently work here</label>
      </div>
      <div class="position-start col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>Jan</option>
            <option>Feb</option>
            <option>Mar</option>
            <option>Apr</option>
            <option>May</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>2011</option>
            <option>2012</option>
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2014</option>
            <option>2015</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <p>to</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 position-end">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>Jan</option>
            <option>Feb</option>
            <option>Mar</option>
            <option>Apr</option>
            <option>May</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>2011</option>
            <option>2012</option>
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2014</option>
            <option>2015</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="clearfix">
  <h3>FORM 2</h3>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Time Period</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 checkbox-parent">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-present" />
        <label for="work-2">I currently work here</label>
      </div>
      <div class="position-start col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>Jan</option>
            <option>Feb</option>
            <option>Mar</option>
            <option>Apr</option>
            <option>May</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>2011</option>
            <option>2012</option>
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2014</option>
            <option>2015</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <p>to</p>
      </div>
      <div class="position-end col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>Jan</option>
            <option>Feb</option>
            <option>Mar</option>
            <option>Apr</option>
            <option>May</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>2011</option>
            <option>2012</option>
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2014</option>
            <option>2015</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```